# Itext and lowagie stopped working - NoSuchMethod getCharBBox(char)

Tags: java, maven, itext

My project is using the older (lgpl licensed) iText and it stopped working. I have reverted the last commits but it didn't help. The error is:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'int[] com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(char)'`

I have navigated trough the decompiled files and I've found those (missing) methods... I really don't know what is going on.

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>  
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Yeah, there are two itext dependencies. But I have to say that two days ago this was working...

Was there a change on the old iText which broke it?

Answer (score 0):

You nearly answered the question by yourself:

> Yeah, there are two itext dependencies.

The truce is that you added iText **thrice**!

It doesn't make sense to have iText thrice as a dependency. If you are using `com.lowagie` iText then remove the others and your pom.xml should look like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>  
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you want to use a newer iText then use [openPDF](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF).